# Adding different image to serve as thumbnail than the original one in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am working on a (gamification) Rails project where each user can be assigned multiple badges based on certain criteria. For the same, I need to make a generic module to upload new badges with 2 different versions of each badge (instead of different resolutions of the same image), one for the main dashboard and one to serve as a thumbnail in other places.

What would be the most optimal way to implement this, perhaps using something like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) so that these images can be accessed like:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

or something similar?

Comment: Why don't you have it in two columns?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this gem [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

You can define version in class with ur custom size

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]

  version :thumb do
   process resize_to_fill: [200,200]
  end

end
```

And call it in view like this

```
uploader.url # => '/url/to/my_file.png'               # size: 800x600
uploader.thumb.url # => '/url/to/thumb_my_file.png'   # size: 200x200
```